# Constrained generic event in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, events

I want to create a message bus such that I can write a publisher as follows:

```
unit Publisher;

interface

type
  TStuffHasHappenedMessage
             = class( TMessage )
               public
                 Text: string;
                 constructor Create( aText: string );
               end;

  TSomeClass = class
                 procedure DoStuff;
               end;

implementation

constructor TStuffHasHappenedMessage.Create( aText: string );
begin
  Text := aText;
end;

procedure TSomeClass.DoStuff;
begin
  ...
  TMessageBus.Notify( Self, TStuffHasHappenedMessage.Create( 'Some Text' ) );
end;

end.
```

And a subscriber as follows:

```
unit Subscriber;

interface

uses
  Publisher;

TMyClass = class
             procedure MyHandler( Sender: TObject; Message: TStuffHasHappenedMessage );
             constructor Create;
           end

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  TMessageBus.Subscribe( TStuffHasHappenedMessage, MyHandler );
end;

procedure TMyClass.MyHandler( Sender: TObject; Message: TStuffHasHappenedMessage );
begin
  ShowMessage( Message.Text )
end;

end.
```

I ultimately want to avoid a type-cast in "MyHandler" by allowing a call to "Subcribe" with
any handler of the generic type:

```
THandler<T:TMessage> = procedure ( Sender: TObject: Message: T );
```

I cannot work out how "TMessageBus.Subscribe" can be declared and implemented to support this

Comment: It's hard to tell you goals here. Code is fragmented and we can't see the design, the motivation, etc. MyClass.MyHandler is odd because it doesn't use Self.

Comment: Sorry - I'll try to make it clearer

Comment: This isn't a good question in my view and will be of little value to others. Hence a low score means it won't be ranked highly when searching.  That's how things are meant to be.

Comment: What is a vote if not a judge of value? We aren't here to help you individually. That's not what Stack Overflow is for. If you have got that impression then I'm afraid you are somewhat mistaken. Stack Overflow is a resource of useful Q&A topics. If we voters feel that they are not going to be useful in the future then we vote down. If we feel that future visitors will find the topic useful, we vote up. If along the way you get help for your personal problem, then that's good but it's not our primary aim. I suggest that you read the [help] again, and if that doesn't resolve it, take it to meta.

Comment: I understand. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check how standard [TMessageManager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Messaging.TMessageManager) is implemented. I don't think what you want to achieve is possible currently in Delphi, because you can't store objects of different classes in a list and then extract without casting to appropriate class at compile time.

```
type
  TStringMessage = TMessage<string>;

procedure TForm1.Button9Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TStringMessage,
    procedure(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage)
  begin
    ShowMessage(TStringMessage(M).Value);
  end);

  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SendMessage(Self, TStringMessage.Create('test'), True);
end;
```

**Update**

Actually with some RTTI help I think it is possible to do something close to what you want.

With unit below you can write following

```
type
  TTestMessage = class(TMessage)
    Test: string;
    constructor Create(const ATest: string);
  end;

constructor TTestMessage.Create(const ATest: string);
begin
  Test := ATest;
end;

procedure HandleMessage(const ASender: TObject; const AMyTestMessage: TTestMessage);
begin
  ShowMessage(AMyTestMessage.Test);
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TPublisher<TTestMessage>.Subscribe(HandleMessage);
  MessageBus.SendMessage(Self, TTestMessage.Create('test'));
end;
```

and here is publisher, note that file have to be called `UPublisher.pas`

```
unit UPublisher;

interface

uses System.Messaging;

type
  TPublisherBase = class
  protected
    procedure SendMessageM(const ASender: TObject; const AMessage: TMessage); virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TPublisherBaseClass = class of TPublisherBase;

  TPublisher<T: class> = class(TPublisherBase)
  private
    type
      THandler = procedure(const Sender: TObject; const AMessage: T);
  private
    class var FHandlers: TArray<THandler>;
    class var FPublisher: TPublisher<T>;
  protected
    procedure SendMessageM(const ASender: TObject; const AMessage: TMessage); override;
    class procedure SendMessage(const ASender: TObject; const AMessage: T);
  public
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;
    class procedure Subscribe(const AHandler: THandler);
  end;

  TMessageBus = class
  strict private
    FPublishers: TArray<TPublisherBase>;
  private
    procedure RegisterPublisher(const APublisher: TPublisherBase);
  public
    procedure SendMessage(const ASender: TObject; const AMessage: TMessage);
    constructor Create;
  end;

var
  MessageBus: TMessageBus;

implementation

constructor TMessageBus.Create;
begin
  FPublishers := [];
end;

procedure TMessageBus.RegisterPublisher(const APublisher: TPublisherBase);
begin
  FPublishers := FPublishers + [APublisher];
end;

procedure TMessageBus.SendMessage(const ASender: TObject; const AMessage: TMessage);
var
  Publisher: TPublisherBase;
  PublisherType: string;
begin
  PublisherType := 'UPublisher.TPublisher<' + AMessage.QualifiedClassName + '>';

  for Publisher in FPublishers do
  begin
    if Publisher.QualifiedClassName = PublisherType then
    begin
      Publisher.SendMessageM(ASender, AMessage);
    end;
  end;
end;

class constructor TPublisher<T>.Create;
begin
  FHandlers := [];
  FPublisher := TPublisher<T>.Create;
  MessageBus.RegisterPublisher(FPublisher);
end;

class destructor TPublisher<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FPublisher.Free;
end;

class procedure TPublisher<T>.Subscribe(const AHandler: THandler);
begin
  FHandlers := FHandlers + [@AHandler];
end;

procedure TPublisher<T>.SendMessageM(const ASender: TObject; const AMessage: TMessage);
begin
  SendMessage(ASender, T(AMessage));
end;

class procedure TPublisher<T>.SendMessage(const ASender: TObject; const AMessage: T);
var
  Handler: THandler;
begin
  for Handler in FPublisher.FHandlers do
  begin
    Handler(ASender, AMessage);
  end;
end;

initialization
  MessageBus := TMessageBus.Create;
finalization
  MessageBus.Free;
end.
```

Comment: You *can* have an array of class references `array of TClass` or even a list of them `TList<TClass>`. The whole of Delphi's component infrastructure relies on having "different classes in a list", essentially a `TList<TComponentClass>`

Comment: @Nat what I meant was 'objects of different classes'

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. You can actually, but you need some structure around that. See my answer.

Comment: Your comment to my answer was correct. I've deleted it.

Comment: Thank's everyone for you valuable input. Very helpful.